# Use Google authentication for pages within a website

Tags: security

We are trying to restrict certain pages of our website, and we use Google Apps for Business, so we were hoping we could leverage Google authentication. Everything I've found on the topic though is specific to using Google authentication to access WordPress (say as a site admin). We are just trying to restrict pages of our published site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use google authentication to connect as admin, then accessing published site pages are no different than connecting to a different user role.

Make a new user role (say subscriber) and make your pages accessible to that particular role based users only. Make sure they don't have access to anything else than these pages only, if you don't want them to see anything else like certain wp admin features etc. Then connecting to any user within this rule using google authentication will fill your need/target.

If you are new to custom user roles, there are plenty of plugins in WordPress plugin directory supporting user role creation/modification